# Wrong resource bundle is loaded after deploy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have a strange problem that: my application loads resources well when running at IDE locally(IDEA, windows 7 , lang = Chinese). But after I deploy the war to Linux, something very strange goes wrong.

The problem contains in this log:

```
[LangService#getInstance]: lang = zh_CN, resourceBundle: en's instance is returned
```

**Which means the clients wants Chinese Service but it give me the English one.**

But the application runs well when I run at IDEA, both on mine and my colleague one(eclipse) .

The three properties file are :

```
strings.properties //Chinese text 
strings_en.properties//English text
strings_zh_CN.properties//Chinese text
```

some relative code(I use Singleton pattern to return TWO Singletons of LangService):

```
public class LangService {

/*******************static variable*****************/

/***constants*****/
public static final String LANG_ENGLISH = "en";
public static final String LANG_CHINESE = "zh_CN";//Chinese
private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "bundle.strings";

private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LangService.class);


/**
 * Chinse service and RB*
 */
private static  ResourceBundle zhRB;
private static  LangService zhService;
static {
    try{
        zhRB = ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_PATH, new Locale(LANG_CHINESE));
        zhService =  new LangService(LANG_CHINESE);
    }
}


/**English Service , lazy instantiation**/
private static  ResourceBundle enRB = null ;
private static  LangService enService =  null;

/******************instance variale*********************/
private ResourceBundle resourceBundle = zhRB;//Chinese RB by default

//private constructor
private LangService(String lang){
    ResourceBundle rb = zhRB;//by default, this will be Chinese RB

    if(checkEnglish(lang)){
        if (null ==enRB ){//English RB is not loaded yet
            enRB = ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_PATH, new Locale(LANG_ENGLISH));
        }
        rb = enRB;
    }

    this.resourceBundle= rb;// set rb accordingly
}


public static synchronized LangService getInstance(String lang){
    LangService instance = zhService;//Chinese service by default

    if(checkEnglish(lang)){//want English service 
        if (enService ==null){//not init yet
            enService =  new LangService(LANG_ENGLISH);
        }
        instance = enService;
    }
    log.info("[LangService#getInstance]: lang = " +lang + ", resourceBundle: "+instance.resourceBundle.getLocale() +"'s instance is returned");//here , we can see the problem
    return instance;
}


private static boolean checkEnglish(String lang){
    if(lang == null|| "".equals(lang)) return false;
    return LANG_ENGLISH.equals(lang) || lang.startsWith("en");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The bug you are experience is trivial:

```
new Locale(LANG_CHINESE)
```

Given the fact that you have defined the constant like this:

```
public static final String LANG_CHINESE = "zh_CN";
```

It really becomes:

```
zhRB = ResourceBundle.getBundle(RESOURCE_PATH, new Locale("zh_CN"));
```

The problem is, there is no such constructor in the `Locale` class that will consume Java locale identifier, instead you have other choices:

A) Use two argument constructor:

```
Locale chineseLocale = new Locale("zh", "CN");
```

B) Use predefined Locale constant:

```
Locale chineseLocale = Locale.CHINA;
```

C) From Java 7 up, use language tag:

```
public static final String SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE = "zh-CN";
Locale chineseLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag(SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE);
```

Personally, I prefer the last one, but it really depends on your environment.